# Is it possible to get a MaterialPageRoute in a Raised Button

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is it possible to close a MaterialPageRoute in a RaisedButton? I want to do it this way, if you enter 1 in the textfield and go to page 2. Is that possible and if so how?

```
Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Test"),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                      onPressed: (){
                        if (_controller.text.contains("Test"))
                        //this below doesnt work?
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                         builder: (BuildContext context) => new Menue()   
                        ); 
                        debugPrint("its correct");
                      },
                    )
                  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Navigator` to perform the navigation, passing the `MaterialPageRoute`

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new Menue()));
```

FYI, in dart you can also omit the `new` keyword.